# symfony jquery ajax json error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, symfony

**my controller:**

> jjgp_bisa_bis_crea_mensaje: 
>       pattern:  /creamensaje
>       defaults: { _controller: JJGPBisaBisBundle:Default:creamensaje }

**my Action function**

> public function creamensajeAction() {
>
> ```
>     $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
>
>     $usermail = $request->request->get('usermail');
>     $mensaje = $request->request->get('mensaje');
>     $leido = $request->request->get('leido');
>     $fecha = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
>
>     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
>     $mensajes = $em->getRepository('JJGPBisaBisBundle:Mensajes')->CrearMensajes($usermail, $mensaje, $fecha, $leido);
>     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
>     $em->persist($mensajes);
>     $em->flush();
>
>     // response test
>
>     $return['usermail'] = 'a';
>     $return['mensaje'] = "b";
>     $return['leido'] = "c";
>
>     return json_encode($return);
> }
> ```

**my jquery:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{{ path('jjgp_bisa_bis_crea_mensaje') }}',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {    // test vars only
        usermail: "email",
        mensaje: $txt_enviar ,
        leido: "no"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.msg);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error"); // always jump here!! that's the problem!
    }
});
```

All of this seems work ok, I can see how the database is growing up and works fine, but jquery always alerts me error function, and I don't know why!

I think it can be the controller path but I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

Your action has to return some sort of `Response` object.  In your case, you can use a JsonResponse.  include this statement:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
```

And the you can replace this line

```
return json_encode($return);
```

with this:

```
return new JsonResponse($return);
```

You may also want to look at what error is thrown.  Without the error message, it is kinda hard to see exactly what the problem is.